# From a compact topological group to a commutative Hopf algebra

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, hopf-algebras

As we know we can associate a commutative Hopf algebra to any compact topological group as follows:

Let $G$ be a compact topological group. Consider the space of continuous
functions on $G$ denoted by $C(G)$ together with the following maps:

$(f.h)(g) = f(g)h(g)$, $~~~$ $\Delta(f)(g_1\otimes g_2) = f(g_1g_2)$, $~~~$

$\eta(x) = x 1$ where $1(g)=1$ for all $g\in G$,

$\epsilon(f) = f(e)$ where $e$ is the unit element of $G$,

$S(f)(g) = f(g^{−1})$.

Now my question is that why to be compact is important here for our topological group?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is not clear what your definition of $\Delta(f)$ means.  What is $g_1\otimes g_2$?  If you are claiming this is the comultiplication of a Hopf algebra, you need $\Delta(f)$ to be an element of $C(G)\otimes C(G)$, which it does not appear to be.

Comment: I think you are trying to identify $C(G)\otimes C(G)$ with $C(G\times G)$ (so $g_1\otimes g_2$ actually means the element $(g_1,g_2)\in G\times G$), but this is typically not correct, even if $G$ is compact.  Maybe you mean to be working in some category of Banach spaces so you are taking a completed tensor product?

Comment: Unless your tensor products are completed or something, what you are trying to prove is not true: the image of the map obtained by taking continuous functions from the multiplication $G\times G\to G$ does not in general have image contained in $C(G)\otimes C(G)\subseteq C(G\times G)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks! But this is the usual way of putting Hopf algebra structure on $C(G)$. I just wanted to know why we cannot define it by just assuming $G$ a topological group not a compact topological group?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks! So you mean for to have $C(G)\otimes C(G)\subseteq C(G\times G)$ we do need to work on compact groups?

Comment: No. That is true for all groups (for all spaces, even)

Comment: There is no usual Hopf algebra structure on $C(G)$, at least not in the literal sense using the algebraic tensor product.